# Building grep strings dynamically

Tags: linux, shell, grep, tail

I am writing a shell script to do a "tail" on a growing log file. This script accepts parameters to search for, and incrementally greps the output on them.

For example, if the script is invoked as follows:

```
logs.sh string1 string2
```

it should translate to:

```
tail -f logs.txt | grep string1 | grep string2
```

I am building the list of grep strings like this:

```
full_grep_string=""
for grep_string in $*
do
    full_grep_string="$full_grep_string | grep $grep_string" 
done
```

The string is built correctly, but when I try to finally tag it to the tail command, like so...

```
tail -f $LOG_FILE_PATH $full_grep_string
```

...the grep does not apply, and I get the unfiltered logs.

Am I missing something here? Or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Just a small clarification: Is the idea that your script should output the lines of the log file that contains BOTH string1 and string2, or was your intention to find lines containing any of the strings?

Comment: Also, what shell are you using? bash?

Comment: for me on debian lenny I've to face the problem that two grep combined do not work with tail -f but with just tail

Comment: @Andreas: I suggest he want's to find both, otherwise the combined greps are useless and he could use egrep "string1|string2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eval tail -f $LOG_FILE_PATH $full_grep_string
```

Answer (score 1):

grep buffers the line it found. So modifying your code to

```
full_grep_string="$full_grep_string | grep --line-buffered $grep_string"
```

shall work. I tested it on debian lenny (with bash).

And use the tip of an0

```
eval tail -f ...
```

(All this works for whole words)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.. but it looks like my version of grep is too old to take full word arguments. I'm testing on a SunOS 5.8 box, btw. Very old software. :)